# Multiple videoview one activity

Tags: java, android, android-videoview

Hi i am creating a fitness application and have multiple videos running on one activity. The first video runs fine using the media controller however the following 3 throw a cant play this video error. If anyone could help on this issue that would be great :)

```
    VideoView vid1, vid2, vid3, vid4;
    Button button6;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity12);

    vid1 = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
    String uripath1 = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.inclinedbcurls;
    vid1.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(uripath1));

    MediaController mc1 = new MediaController(this);
    mc1.setMediaPlayer(vid1);
    vid1.setMediaController(mc1);

    vid2 = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView2);
    String uripath2 = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.dumbellbicepcurl;
    vid2.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(uripath2));

    MediaController mc2 = new MediaController(this);
    mc2.setMediaPlayer(vid2);
    vid2.setMediaController(mc2);

    vid3 = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView3);
    String uripath3 = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.dragcurl;
    vid3.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(uripath3));

    MediaController mc3 = new MediaController(this);
    mc3.setMediaPlayer(vid3);
    vid3.setMediaController(mc3);

    vid4 = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView4);
    String uripath4 = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.hammercurls;
    vid4.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(uripath4));

    MediaController mc4 = new MediaController(this);
    mc4.setMediaPlayer(vid4);
    vid4.setMediaController(mc4);



    <ScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="500dp">

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
          android:id="@+id/textView1"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="Incline Dumbell Curl"
          android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
          android:textColor="#87CEFA"
          android:textSize="26dp" />

     <VideoView
          android:id="@+id/videoView1"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="250dp" />

     <TextView
          android:id="@+id/textView2"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="Dumbell Bicep Curl"
          android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
          android:textColor="#87CEFA"
          android:textSize="26dp" />

     <VideoView
          android:id="@+id/videoView2"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="250dp" />

     <TextView
          android:id="@+id/textView3"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="Drag Curl"
          android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
          android:textColor="#87CEFA"
          android:textSize="26dp" />

 <VideoView
          android:id="@+id/videoView3"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="250dp" />

 <TextView
          android:id="@+id/textView4"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="Hammer Curls"
          android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
          android:textColor="#87CEFA"
          android:textSize="26dp" />

      <VideoView
          android:id="@+id/videoView4"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="250dp" />

     </LinearLayout>
     </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use 3 different fragments in your activity and put each movie in one fragment.
[Android dev>Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)